# Dynamics 365 - 'PluginAssembly' entity doesn't contain attribute

Tags: dynamic, crm

When create a connection using PluginRegistration, I was getting the error below.

'PluginAssembly' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'packageid' and NameMapping = 'Platform'.

Can you offer a solution ? Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A8Dl.png)

Comment: I had the same problem. For now it looks like the xrm toolbox version is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Recently Plugin Registration Tool added new features and if the user used to connect has not a System Administrator role errors can happen.
I don't know if it is related to your case but I will check the roles first.

Also XrmToolBox has a Plugin Registration Tool (you can find it inside the Tool Library) you can try with this version and see if you can connect or not.

Comment: I am sure that account is System admin, so it not for this reason. I try to look the entity table in database, then i find the question, the entity table doesn't contain packageid field.  It's the metadata cache in server side?

Comment: did you try with XrmToolBox?

Comment: XrmToolbox is work sucessfully. So I think it's a updated error in PluginRegistration tool.

Comment: If you can share some additional details, like exact Dynamics instance version and the instance url (without sensitive data, if you are connecting to a specific region like China your url may differ from the usual <organizationname>.crm<number>.dynamics.com) I will pass this information to Microsoft

Comment: I'm sorry. Because the security management, i can't provide the connection data.

Comment: I don't need the connection data, I need the instance version (that is just a number like 9.2.22022.00134, you click on "About" in the top right settings wheel) and the format of your instance url. for example one of my trial is: https://<organizatiotrialname>.crm4.dynamics.com yours will be something like https://<organizationame>.crm.dynamics.cn if is under China region. Inside this blog post you can find some regions https://arunpotti.com/2021/03/15/dynamics-365-crm-online-regions-list/, I don't need the real url, but the region is important especially when dealing with specific regions

Comment: The dynamics crm we used is on-premises with version 1612(9.0.8.9)(DB 9.0.8.9) . I downloaded the Plugin Registration Tool with version: 9.0.0.9651. By the way you are right, the server is in China

Comment: Because your setup is on-premises the reason you are getting the error is due to the new changes of Plugin Registration Tool in the latest versions, you correctly used a previous NuGet package in order to connect to your on-premise instance. Keep using that version and you will be ok. I will advise Microsoft that the latest version of PRT can cause this kind of issues when connecting to on-premise